# execute linux shell permisson denied,but i have assigned permissions,how can i fix it?

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

I write a shell named test.sh in /run path and execute `chmod 777 test.sh`  command.
   then I run `./test.sh` ,it displays permission denied.
   but I run `sh test.sh`,it's ok.
   Then I copy test.sh to my home directory and run `./test.sh` ,it works.
   can somebody tell me why?
   [my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2fUD.png)

Comment: Can you update this question with `test.sh` content?

Comment: Check the mount flags for the partition which includes `/run`; they probably include `noexec`. You don't usually put scripts in that directory. Also, `777` is a bad habit; executable files should not be writeable (at least by anyone other than the owner.)

Comment: @rici,the /run path has noexec flag.how can I remove the flag,my os is ubuntu 16.04.thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to put the shell script in /run?

Comment: I have solved it ,use the command `mount -o remount,exec /run`,remove the noexec flag.then i can run `./test.sh`.thank you .@rici

Comment: i use cloudera to install hue in my marchine.the installation generate "altscript.sh" in "/run/cloudera-scm-agent/process/",but the shell can't be executed,so the installation stucks.so i write a shell to test it .@rici